# Detect when developer mode is enabled

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

Is there a way to detect when `Developer mode` is enabled?

The reason I'd like to detect this, is because my extension produces a lot of debug information in the console. And to avoid unnecessary performance lose, I'd like to disable output if dev mode is disabled.
At the moment, I'm using this little hack, which only output data if extension is unpacked:

```
chrome.management.getSelf().then(data=>debug.show=data.installType=="development");
const debug = new Proxy({show:false,void:()=>{}},
{
    get(target, prop)
    {
        return target.show ? console[prop].bind(console) : target.void;
    }
});
```

But I'd like to be able to test it in packed state as well.

Comment: There's no way.

Comment: @wOxxOm in that case, do I need to worry about performance and remove all `console` calls before publishing the extension?

Comment: You can add `console.log = ()=>{}` in your production code.